# string are splitted in 'list()' and not in '[]' why?

Tags: python, string, list

I have been working in a project then I accidently 
discovered when I pass string,they are splitted in `list()` but when I pass the same string to  `[ ]` there is no splitting into single letters of  the string.

Can anyone tell me what happend here?

```
>>> y = list("hello")
>>> y
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> z = ["hello"]
>>> z
['hello']
```

Comment: Did you check the docs for [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [`list` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) takes an iterable as an argument and constructs a list from the items of that iterable. In your case it will grab each individual sub string in the string and us them as items.

On the contrary, `[]` is an alternate constructor that constructs a list from the elements the comma-separated values that are provided, no additional actions are performed.

You could achieve a similar result with `[]` in Python 3 by unpacking the string inside the square brackets:

```
s = "hello"
l = [*s]
print(l) # ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

In **both** Python versions, you can get the *same* result with a comprehension:

```
l = [char for char in s]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) is a `builtin` that takes an *iterable* and turns it into a list.

`[]` on the other hand is a language construct for *defining* lists. To achieve the same results with the construct `[]` you can use a comprehension:

```
>>> z = [i for i in "hello"]
>>> z
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are iterable. The `list` function (really it's a type, but it's callable) iterates over its argument, making each element of the iterable (in your case, each character of a string) an element of the resulting list.

That's pretty much the same for any iterables. What you are doing is the string equivalent of

```
>>> list([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> [[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Which is to say, in the second case you get a list containing a single iterable while in the first one you get a list made up of the individual elements of the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

in `>>> y = list("hello")`
You ask python to build a list from `"hello"` si it cut the string in element

and in `>>> z = ["hello"]`
you make a list with a single element `hello`

Answer (score 0):

The list() method makes a list out of given input.

The version with square brackets implies you want to create a list with one element, your string. Therefore it is not splitted up.

Answer (score 0):

y = list("hello")
list() is a built-in function that takes an iterable and "Return a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable‘s items" (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

z = ["hello"]
This is just a list with a single element (of type string) on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example;

```
>>> y = list("hello")
```

you are casting a string "hello" to a list

In the second example;

```
>>> z = ["hello"]
```

You are creating an array(list) with one item which is a string with contents "hello"